# haproxy sni for http/3 quic (udp)

Tags: haproxy, sni, quic, http3

I've got haproxy doing sni routing for a bunch of sites without issue. HTTP/2 works great. Is there a way to setup sni type routing for HTTP/3 (quic) without having any certs installed in haproxy?